# How to apply styles to a [readonly] input element with Angular conditions applied?

Tags: css, angular, readonly

**I am trying to style a readonly `<input>` element with a color**. I have looked into the different code and only found the explanation for

```
<input readonly>
```

or

```
<input readonly="true">
```

but with

```
<input [readonly]="(!groupForm.errors?.validateCode) ? true : null  &&
    (groupForm.dirty || groupForm.touched)"  type="text" id="specNr"
    class="form-control"  formControlName="specNr" >
```

I can't find a solution. I have tried with the following CSS but it did not work.

```
input[readonly]{
  background-color: #f17517;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything you did right here only you need to write style in following the way to solve your problem.

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Input Demo</h1>

<h3>Read Only Input Styling</h3>
<input [readonly]="true">

<h3>Read Only Input Styling</h3>
<input [readonly]="false">
```

**app.component.css**

```
input:-moz-read-only { /* For Firefox */
   background-color: #f17517;
}

input:read-only { 
   background-color: #f17517;
}
```

**[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu38lq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: I will try that. Get back in a while

Comment: It did not work. Can that be because of the form-control styling

Comment: yes that might be an issue. you can add this style in your global style.css to solve issue

Comment: are you using any css framework for styling? like bootstrap or something like that!

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Have you tried adding style in style.css global stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

This combination worked

```
.form-control[readonly] {
  background-color: #fcfcfc !important;
}
```

together with this

```
<input readonly="{{(!groupForm.errors?.validateFc) ? true : null  && (groupForm.dirty || groupForm.touched)}}"  type="text" id="fc"  class="form-control"  formControlName="fcn"  >
```

Thanks for inputs

Answer (score -1):

Yes bootstrap.

(Using homeaccount)